# Video screensaver in mountain lion

Tags: macos, video, screensaver

Can I somehow have a video loop as a screensaver in mountain lion?
I remember the `Save Hollywood` app that worked for leopard, but nothing since then.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Save Hollywood](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/SaveHollywood/about.html) has been updated for OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and is available as freeware.

Other paid app options are [Video Screensaver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id721318316) (on MAS) and [My Living Desktop](http://www.mylivingdesktop.com/).

Comment: oh cool! i actually made a screensaver myself with quartz. :)